# Prove the Dirichlet funtion continuity on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: calculus

I am considering the funtion

$$f:[0,1]\times[0,1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$$

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }\; (x,y) \in[0,1]\times[0,1]\cap(\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}),
\\{}\\
1&\text{if }\; (x,y) \in[0,1]\times[0,1]\cap(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q})^{c}. \end{cases}$$

I have proved that this function is not integrable, but I want to know how I can prove that it is not continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing that $Q$ is dense in $R$, select a pair $(x,y)$ of reals inferior to $1$ make a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ of a pair of rational numbers converges to $(x,y)$

Ab absurdo, if $f$ is continous, then $$\lim_{n ->\infty} f((x_n,y_n)))=f((x,y))$$

Yet, $\forall n, \ f((x_n,y_n))=0$ (because $(x_n,y_n)$ is a rational couple so taking the limit $f(x,y)=0$ which is absurd because $(x,y)$ are real.

Conclusion : $f$ isn't continous.